# Cocoapods pod stable build setting

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, cocoapods

Is there a way to add build setting in a `cocoapods` pod without direct changing Pods project or other auto-generated stuff, so it will still be in place after `pod install`? Being specific, I need to set `DISABLE_MIXPANEL_AB_DESIGNER=1` in Mixpanel pod to avoid crashes.

I've found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942517/cocoapods-pods-project-build-settings), but it's outdated & looks strange because (as far as I understand) `podspec` file is created by pod owner, not user.

Comment: Could the `post_install` hook be of use here? https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#post_install

Comment: @Hodson Indeed, it could :) I've posted an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Hodson, it is the solution. Slightly modified the example from [documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#post_install), we get

```
post_install do |installer|

    #Specify what and where has to be added
    targetName = 'Mixpanel'
    settingKey = 'DISABLE_MIXPANEL_AB_DESIGNER'
    settingValue = 1

    #Find the pod which should be affected
    targets = installer.pods_project.targets.select { |target| target.name == targetName }
    target = targets[0]

    #Do the job
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings[settingKey] = settingValue
    end
end
```

Just add this code to your podfile. Obviously, in the same way you can make any changes to autogenerated pods project, and they won't ever get lost.